# What kind of ML model can find missing parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-modeling, prediction, missing-data

Given a data set, such as:

`(FirstName, LastName, Sex, DateOfBirth, HairColor, EyeColor, Height, Weight, Location)`

that *some model* can train on, what kind of Machine Learning paradigm can be used to predict missing values if only given some of them?

**Example:**

***Given:***

`(FirstName: John, LastName: Doe, Sex: M, Height: (5,10))`

**What model could predict the missing values?**

`(DateOfBirth, HairColor, EyeColor, Weight, Location)`

In other words, the model should be able to take any of the fields as inputs, and "fill in" any that are missing.

And what type of ML/DL is this even called?

Comment: Note: The choice of fields was arbitrary; it could be a data set of food recipes, or pc components, or whatever. My question is simply, what kind of ML handles this kind of problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to fill missing values with an algorithm, this is called imputing missing data. If you're using Python, the scikit-learn library has a number of imputation algorithms that you can explore in [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.impute).

One nice algorithm is KNNImputer, which looks `n_neighbors` most similar observations to the current observation and fills the missing data with mean for the column from those similar observations. Read more here:  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I know my question was a bit vague, but you provided me with what I need to continue my research. I will be looking at those suggestions and other imputation algorithms that may suit my data model. Thank you again!

Comment: Cool. Feel free to upvote if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot of missing values in a row, first need to understand: will it add value to my problem? Else drop such rows which have a lot of missing values.

One way to handle: Remove the target variable. Using the features which do not have missing values, predict columns that have missing values. Use ML algorithms, to predict and fill those values. Then again use previously imputed missing values to predict other missing values.

Eg: if features and target are: X1, X2, X3, X4, Y
Let X1 and X2 do not have missing values, X3 and X4 have missing values.
First, keep aside Y. Using X1 and X2, fill missing values in X3 with the help of ML algorithms. Again, using X1, X2, X3 fill missing values in X4. Then finally predict the target values (Y).

I have used this method in hackathons and got good results. Before applying this, first, try to get a good understanding of the data. The approach might be slightly different from what you have asked, but this is a decent approach for such problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. This does help me with my methodology. My original question is what kinds of prediction models would be adequate for predicting missing values of various types? There are so many models out there, and many are way beyond what suspect I need. Some of the data is numerical, some of it is limited strings (like enum values), and (the hard part) is a string that contains "natural" language (I say "natural" because it is an extremely limited subset of English that follows a strict syntax). I have my work cut out for me. lol.